# gstreamer recording m3u8 stream

Tags: gstreamer, m3u8, gst-launch

I'm trying to record stream from m3u8 file.
This pipeline works:
`gst-launch-0.10 -e souphttpsrc location=(mysrc.m3u8) ! queue ! hlsdemux ! queue ! mpegtsparse ! queue ! mpegtsdemux ! queue !  audio/mpeg ! queue ! filesink location=test.ts` 
and (sometimes) record audio stream.
But i can't record video, whatever i do it crashes.
I tried something like this:
`gst-launch-0.10 souphttpsrc location=(mysrc.m3u8) ! queue ! hlsdemux ! queue ! mpegtsparse ! queue ! mpegtsdemux ! queue ! video/x-264 ! queue ! filesink location=test.ts` 
But it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You are using gstreamer 0.10 which is obsolete and unmantained, all users should upgrade to the 1.x series.

Given that warning, it is not clear whether you want to save the mpegts stream or the streams inside it.

To save the mpegts stream you can just do:

```
gst-launch-1.0 http://path/to/your/stream.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! filesink
```

Be aware that if the HLS playlist contains multiple bitrates hlsdemux might switch bitrate and it will fail as gst-launch-1.0 isn't capable of handling this. (it is a debugging and testing tool). You can likely set a fixed "connection-speed" to make it always use the same bitrate you desire to overcome this issue.

If you want to get only the video stream and you know it is H264, try:

```
gst-launch-1.0 http://path/to/your/stream.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux ! queue ! video/x-h264 ! filesink
```

It might be a better idea to save it to a container format to allow easier use later, with something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 http://path/to/your/stream.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux ! queue ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink
```

But, as I said, please move to 1.x, HLS is much better at 1.x than it was in 0.10 and it should work.

Comment: I have to get video and audio separately, to different files, but now i focus on getting whatever that will be working. I am trying      gst-launch-1.0 http://path/to/your/stream.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! filesink but when i try to play it with vlc it crashes after about 1 second. Maybe it is because there are actually multiple bitrates in h3u8 file. I dont know how to use connection-speed

Comment: connection-speed is set just like any other property. hlsdemux property=value. Check gst-inspect-1.0 hlsdemux for the available and descriptions.